# How to make existing values to null from the existing plsql logic

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE main_tab (
    seq_id      NUMBER(10),
    e_id        NUMBER(10),
    code        NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_main_tab PRIMARY KEY(seq_id)
);

INSERT INTO main_tab VALUES(1,11,3);

CREATE TABLE transact_tab (
    seq_id,
    e_id,
    code        NUMBER(10),
    start_date  DATE,
    end_date    DATE
);
```

I have two tables `main_tab` and `transact_tab` wherein I need to insert the records into the `transact_tab` table based on the column `code` of table `main_tab`.
Ex. If  `code = 3`  then in the table `transact_tab` it should load 3 records like 1, 2, and 3 with the `start_date` and `end_date` column as `SYSDATE` just for the current `code` value `end_date` would be null.

Code for the above requirement: -

```
DECLARE 
  l_transact_row transact_tab%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM main_tab) LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. r.code LOOP
      BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO l_transact_row 
          FROM transact_tab
         WHERE e_id = r.e_id AND code = i; 
        IF l_transact_row.end_date IS NULL AND i <> r.code THEN
          UPDATE transact_tab SET end_date = SYSDATE WHERE e_id = r.e_id AND code = i;
        END IF;
      EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO transact_tab (e_id, code,start_date, end_date)
          VALUES (r.e_id, i, SYSDATE, CASE WHEN i = r.code THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END);  
      END ;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Database Version: Oracle 18c.

This code is perfectly working fine for top down approach wherein I need to load the data into the `transact_tab` but if my `code` gets decreased then the logic should handle this scenario as well. Example..if `code` gets changed from 3 to 2 then in this case it should update the already existing values of `transact_tab` to NULL if code is decreased.

Expected output of `transact_tab` if the `code` is decreased from 3 to 2 in `main_tab` should be:

```
+------+------+------------+----------+
| e_id | code | start_date | end_date |
+------+------+------------+----------+
|   11 |    1 | 19-06-22   | 19-06-22 |
|   11 |    2 | 19-06-22   | NULL     |
|   11 |    3 | NULL       | NULL     |
+------+------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: How will you decrease the value? Through an update statement or insert a new row with decreased value? Please post the sample data from both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited version with less code. Basicaly - it works, but I didn't test all possible waays of changing the value of CODE on different days. Probably there is some more tuning to be done. Try it and check it.

```sql
Declare
    maxRepeats      Number(3) := 0;
    subMaxCode      Number(3) := 0;
Begin
    FOR r IN(SELECT * FROM a_main_tab) LOOP
        maxRepeats := r.CODE;
        SELECT Nvl(Max(CODE), 0) Into subMaxCode FROM a_transact_tab WHERE SEQ_ID = r.SEQ_ID And E_ID = r.E_ID; -- And start_date Is Not Null;
        FOR i IN 1..maxRepeats LOOP 
            If subMaxCode >= 0 And subMaxCode = maxRepeats THEN         
                EXIT;
            ElsIf subMaxCode >= 0 And subMaxCode < maxRepeats And i > subMaxCode THEN       
                        Begin
                            INSERT INTO a_transact_tab (seq_id, e_id, code, start_date, end_date)
                            VALUES(r.seq_id, r.e_id, i, SYSDATE, CASE WHEN i = maxRepeats THEN Null ELSE SYSDATE END);
                            commit;
                        End;
            ElsIf subMaxCode >= 0 And subMaxCode < maxRepeats And i <= subMaxCode THEN
                        Begin
                            UPDATE A_TRANSACT_TAB
                            SET start_date = CASE WHEN start_date Is Null Then SYSDATE ELSE start_date END,
                                end_date = CASE WHEN end_date Is Null Then SYSDATE ELSE end_date END
                            WHERE seq_id = r.seq_id and e_id = r.e_id and code = i;
                            commit;
                        End;
            ElsIf subMaxCode >= 0 And subMaxCode >= maxRepeats And i <= subMaxCode THEN             --UPD_x_TO_y
                Begin
                    UPDATE A_TRANSACT_TAB updt
                    SET updt.start_date = CASE WHEN CODE > maxRepeats THEN Null ELSE CASE WHEN updt.start_date Is Not Null THEN updt.start_date ELSE SYSDATE END END,
                        updt.end_date = CASE WHEN CODE >= maxRepeats THEN Null ELSE CASE WHEN updt.start_date Is Not Null THEN updt.start_date ELSE SYSDATE END END
                    WHERE updt.seq_id = r.seq_id and updt.e_id = r.e_id and updt.code Between 1 and subMaxCode;
                    commit;
                End;
                EXIT;
            End If;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
End;
```

After this (2nd) edit and simullations the results of testing are here:

```sql
-- 17-JUN-22 Code is 3 *transact table empty
-- SEQ_ID     E_ID   CODE   START_DATE  END_DATE
-- ------   ------  -----   ----------  ----------
--      1       11      1   17-JUN-22   17-JUN-22
--      1       11      2   17-JUN-22   17-JUN-22
--      1       11      3   17-JUN-22   
--
--  ----------------------------------------------
-- 18-JUN-22 Code changed from 3 to 2
-- SEQ_ID     E_ID   CODE   START_DATE  END_DATE
-- ------   ------  -----   ----------  ----------
--      1       11      1   17-JUN-22   17-JUN-22
--      1       11      2   17-JUN-22   
--      1       11      3       
--
--  ----------------------------------------------
-- 19-JUN-22 Code changed from 2 to 5
-- SEQ_ID     E_ID   CODE   START_DATE  END_DATE
-- ------   ------  -----   ----------  ----------
--      1       11      1   17-JUN-22   17-JUN-22
--      1       11      2   17-JUN-22   19-JUN-22
--      1       11      3   19-JUN-22   19-JUN-22
--      1       11      4   19-JUN-22   19-JUN-22
--      1       11      5   19-JUN-22   
--
--  ----------------------------------------------
-- 20-JUN-22 (1st) Code changed from 5 to 4
-- SEQ_ID     E_ID   CODE   START_DATE  END_DATE
-- ------   ------  -----   ----------  ----------
--      1       11      1   17-JUN-22   17-JUN-22
--      1       11      2   17-JUN-22   19-JUN-22
--      1       11      3   19-JUN-22   19-JUN-22
--      1       11      4   19-JUN-22   
--      1       11      5       
--
--  ----------------------------------------------
-- 20-JUN-22 (2nd) Code changed from 4 to 7
-- SEQ_ID     E_ID   CODE   START_DATE  END_DATE
-- ------   ------  -----   ----------  ----------
--      1       11      1   17-JUN-22   17-JUN-22
--      1       11      2   17-JUN-22   19-JUN-22
--      1       11      3   19-JUN-22   19-JUN-22
--      1       11      4   19-JUN-22   20-JUN-22
--      1       11      5   20-JUN-22   20-JUN-22
--      1       11      6   20-JUN-22   20-JUN-22
--      1       11      7   20-JUN-22
```

Comment: @d r Thanks for this but can't we simplify this code with less coding? Can't we add one more IF condition like if current_code < existing_code then update start_date and end_date ELSE my existing logic. Or if possible can we make it simple code instead of making it complex

Comment: You can implement all the tests directly, they are here for understanding the logic but also to make the code more readable. You need, though, the two max variables because they are used in inserts/updates. I'm afraid that the code with all complicated expresions built into IF commands will be hard to read and manage in the future. But it is your call after all. So, conclusion is "Yes" it is possible to have less coding, but not sure that will simplify anything.

Comment: And there is still a question what to do if decreased CODE got increased again. There is a possibility that some records should be inserted and some other updated...

Comment: @d r Yes if the same record again got increased then it should behave like the earlier logic which is insert into the ```transact_tab```. Thats the reason if we can make this code little lesser. Can you help here? Just need to add bottom-up approach

Comment: Yes I can but in te morning. Have something else right now.

Comment: @d r Thanks for the hope meanwhile I will also give it a try

Comment: One more thing... We ended with three records in transact and the CODE is 2.If it is increased to 5 what happens with the dates in 3 existing records and what in new ones? Wil they have all the same dates and, if so, which ones - already existing or new sysdate?

Comment: @d r No they will have different dates. Suppose today we ran this proc for code 3 then after 2 days code increased to 5 then the start_date and end_date would be the current date on which we ran this proc and should not overwrite the existing start_date and end_date

Comment: @Vicky  There is edited version now iin the answer. Regards...

Comment: @Vicky Done some more tests (and a bit of fine tuning) and it looks ok to me. There are test results within the answer. Hopefully, it will help you. Regards...

Answer (score 1):

Cant you use something like following -

```
insert into transact_tab (e_id,code, start_date,end_date) 
select e_id,level,
case when code<level then null else sysdate end,
case when code<=level then null else sysdate end
from main_tab
connect by level<=3;
```

Refer fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=105bd8ff32e8117c36c0dd3e40b81319).

```
DECLARE 
  l_transact_row transact_tab%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM main_tab) LOOP
    FOR i IN 1 .. r.code LOOP
      BEGIN
        SELECT * INTO l_transact_row 
          FROM transact_tab
         WHERE e_id = r.e_id AND code = i; 
          UPDATE transact_tab SET (start_date,end_date) = (select sysdate,sysdate from dual) WHERE code < r.code;
          UPDATE transact_tab SET (start_date,end_date) = (select null,null from dual) WHERE code > r.code;
          UPDATE transact_tab SET (start_date,end_date) = (select sysdate,null from dual) WHERE code = r.code;
      EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO transact_tab (e_id, code,start_date, end_date)
          VALUES (r.e_id, i, SYSDATE, CASE WHEN i = r.code THEN NULL ELSE SYSDATE END);  
      END ;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Refer to fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6efa231e9fbb9b773e26a501eebd8072).

Using the merge approach, it handles both increase and decrease in code values for main_tab, along with "if code is 3 then there will be 4 entries i.e 0, 1, 2, and 3"

```
merge into transact_tab t1
using 
(select * from 
(select e_id,level-1 as lvl,
case when code<level-1 then null else sysdate end start_date,
case when code<=level-1 then null else sysdate end end_date
from main_tab
connect by level <= 
(select max(code) + 1 from (
(select max(code) code from transact_tab) union all
(select code from main_tab) )
)
 ) ) t2
  on (t1.e_id = t2.e_id
 and t1.code = t2.lvl)
 when matched then
 update set t1.start_date=t2.start_date, t1.end_date=t2.end_date
  when NOT matched then
 insert (e_id,code,start_date,end_date)
 VALUES
 (t2.e_id,t2.lvl,t2.start_date,t2.end_date);
```

Refer to the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f2b4084f410af6fbe1a5a950e2ca9941), to see the merge approach in action.

Comment: Thanks for this but the logic should handle both approach top down as well as bottom up

Comment: If you main_tab is static with just one, row then I have updated the solution modifying your procedure code.

Comment: Thanks for this but for updating start_date and end_date there is separate logic which is. For example if code is 3 then there will be 3 entries in transact_tab and we ran the process today then start_date and end_date for code 1 and 2 will be SYSDATE and for code 3 only start_date will be SYSDATE and end_date will be NULL. Similarly if code got increased from 3 to 5 on say 25-Jun-22 then the end_date of 3 which was NULL previously will become 25-Jun-22 and the remaining code which got inserted which is 4 and 5 same logic for start_date and end_date as explained for code 3

Comment: Logics are already in place for loading and updating the data just I need to handle the backward direction when code get descreased

Comment: Thanks for this but there is small change in it that we have to load entries starting from 0. That is if code is 3 then there will be 4 entries i.e 0, 1, 2, and 3 rest all logic will remain same

Comment: I tried adding MAX(code)+1 in connect by query and in the USING sub query tried adding level - 1 in SELECT query and giving me the 4 rows starting from 0 to 3 but start_date and end_date logic are not giving the correct results

Comment: @Vicky its difficult to comprehend like this. I have posted a fiddle for this and suggest  to use that/modify it and post back, so its more understandable as to what you are trying to do. Also, you may post back few scenarios in your questions along with expected output. As of now the merge matches the expected output you have shared in the question.

Comment: @Vicky I have updated the response to include for "if code is 3 then there will be 4 entries i.e 0, 1, 2, and 3 "